# Error Solo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se introduce con EXISTS

Tags: sql

Hola tengo esta consulta en SQL, pero al ejecutarla me sale este error, alguien que me diga como solucionarlo, por favor....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto y formato código, no en imágenes. Además copia y pega el error completo, no solo lo menciones.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!